# Pandas boolean Series won't plot

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, plot, boolean

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a plot of a Boolean array. However, I'm getting an error, although others seem to have no problems at all with plotting Boolean arrays.

For numeric arrays, it works as expected. So, the code below works just fine.

```
import pandas as pd
series_numeric = pd.Series([0,1,0])
series_numeric.plot()
```

However, for boolean arrays, an error occurs. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
series_bool = pd.Series([False,True,False])
series_bool.plot()
```

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

However, this is strange, as the speaker in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XGycFIe8qE&t=2157s) (at 1:45:48) does not seem to have any problems with plotting boolean arrays.

Hope anyone can help!

Comment: What `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: can reproduce with pandas `0.22.0`, this looks like a bug

Comment: This is the error that I would have expected. I may have missed it in the video, though I didn't see where he was plotting boolean values. What would you like the figure generated by  `series_bool.plot()` to look like?

Comment: I am using Pandas version 0.23.4.

Comment: I had the same question.  If you want to see zeros and ones, then boolean isn't the type you wanted.  Just use `astype` with either `float` or `int`.  As @Peyman has shown.  For brevity, you can `series_bool.mul(1).plot()` as well.

Comment: Can reproduce with pandas version 0.23.4, seems like this detail must have changed in a pandas release since that video was taped. For everyone saying this is expected - in the video from 2017, clearly this exact case works (the only difference being that the series has a timestamp as the index)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

first convert the type and then plot as below:

```
series_bool.astype(float).plot()
```

[image]

P.S., in the video you were referring to, the instructor is plotting True/False as well so this looks like a change in the treatment of boolean by Pandas

Comment: `numerical_status = machine_status=='OK'` returns a boolean series. You can check this by running the following functional equivalent: `(pd.Series(['apple', 'apple', 'banana'])=='apple').plot()`.
My guess is that the way booleans are handled has changed from them being implicitly converted to 0s and 1s as is pythonic, to them being treated as a non-numerical type. Try typing `True+1` in your python console.

Comment: @tobsecret is correct with regard to the boolean series. However the suggestion made by Peyman works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tobsecret you are right! This seems to be related to changes made in the Pandas' handling of boolean! Edited the answer to reflect this!

Answer (score 2):

This is most definitely due to a change in the way `pandas/plotting/_core.py` handles data. If you go to the [source of the current release 0.23.4](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L360), the data_types considered numeric are `np.number, "datetime", "datetimetz", "timedelta"`:

```
    numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(include=[np.number,
                                               "datetime",
                                               "datetimetz",
                                               "timedelta"])

    try:
        is_empty = numeric_data.empty
    except AttributeError:
        is_empty = not len(numeric_data)

    # no empty frames or series allowed
    if is_empty:
        raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
                        'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
```

If we go back a couple releases to the [source of release 0.20.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.0/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L335), this line reads like this:

```
numeric_data = data._convert(datetime=True)._get_numeric_data()
```

This was changed with the release of `0.21.0`